# 'Type mismatch in expression' (MS Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was linked to this, and after spending more than an hour on fiddling with this, I'm afraid I've given up...

A - probably - easy question, although I have no experience with SQL. When I try this (among other variants) in Access, I get a 'type mismatch in expression':

```
SELECT Route_Leg_Passagier.[RouteID], Route_Leg_Passagier.[LegID], Leg.[Startpunt], Leg.[Eindpunt]
FROM Route_Leg_Passagier, Leg
WHERE Route_Leg_Passagier.[LegID] = Leg.[LegID]
AND Route_Leg_Passagier.[RouteID] = '1';
```

Here's the Access file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104521722/Vliegtuigmaatschappij%20-%20Database11.accdb

I want to see `Startpunt` and `Eindpunt` from those `Leg`s where the `RouteID` is 1. `RouteID` and `LegID` are stored in the entity `Route_Leg_Passagier`, but `Startpunt` and `Eindpunt` are in the entity `Leg`.

I'm sorry if this isn't alright, I have no experience with this site. But feel free to criticise me, and thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't Route_Leg_Passagier.[RouteID] an integer value ? In this case, your WHERE condition should look like this :

```
AND Route_Leg_Passagier.[RouteID] = 1;
```

Quotes are for strings or character values

Comment: Mhm, thank you for your (very fast) answers!

Alas, it still doesn't work. That is, I replaced '1' with simply 1, and it gave the same error.

Comment: `RouteID` is text data type.  This was a reasonable guess, but is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Route_Leg_PassagierID.LegID` is autonumber data type; that is actually a numeric data type, a special form of long integer.  `Leg.LegID` is text data type.  And your db includes a relationship between those two tables using that field.

Try these steps:

1. Make a backup copy of your db file.
2. Delete the relationship between `Route_Leg_PassagierID` and `Leg`.
3. Change the data type of `Leg.LegID` to number, long integer.
4. Test the following query.

```sql
SELECT
    rlp.Route_Leg_PassagierID,
    rlp.LegID,
    l.Startpunt,
    l.Eindpunt
FROM
    Route_Leg_Passagier AS rlp
    INNER JOIN Leg AS l
    ON rlp.LegID = l.LegID
WHERE rlp.RouteID='1';
```

You can also recreate the relationship after you correct the data type of `Leg.LegID`, if desired.